# JPackage installed Java program directory structure

Tags: java, jpackage

So I've just gotten jpackage working with a basic test program. I've ran into a problem that will essentially decide if this system will be something I can apply in real projects.

To set this up, the Java program is structured like this:

```
        rootDirectory
        -src folder
        -res folder
```

The program runs from this root directory. Files that I need for the program during runtime is in the res folder. So, the program will do something like `File f = new File("res/file_i_need.png");`.

I export this as a JAR, and now I'm packaging it with jpackage. The installer is made and I install the program. The resulting folder structure is like this:

```
    rootDirectory
        -app folder
            -res folder
            -program.jar
        -runtime folder
        -program.exe
```

So when you run the program, suddenly `File f = new File("res/file_i_need.png");` doesn't work anymore, because the new rootDirectory has buried the res folder in the app folder.

Is there any way to configure jpackage to put the res folder in the root directory, or set it to where the app folder is used as the root directory, or is this something that you're just stuck with?

And to clarify, the following **will not** work for this particular usecase:

- Storing resources in the JAR itself
- Storing resources in other JARs

The entire point is that the user can easily edit/tweak the files in the res folder themselves.

If jpackage can't handle a scenario like this, alternatives are welcome.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why can't you use the path `app-folder/res/file_i_need`?

Comment: The problem is that the program was already built with res/file_i_need, since that's how it works while it's being worked on in eclipse. The app-folder is added automatically by jpackage during the bundling. There's no way to really account for it in the code itself outside of maybe trying to hack in a way to expect the working directories to not match up.

Comment: Provide the prefix to the `res` folder with a system property, which you only set when running from the jpacked version (I imagine jpackage allows you to specify system properties?)

Comment: Can you elaborate further on this, please? Maybe add it as a potential answer to the question.

Comment: As mentioned in the initial post, using getResourceAsStream/including these resources in the JAR itself won't be possible in this scenario. The users need to have easy access to them. This image (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/deploy/img/bundle_file_struc.png) in this article (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm#JSDPG588) actually shows how it looks. The only problem is that the exe is messing with what the root directory should be during runtime.

Comment: Hey! Have you found a solution for this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: Hey Oleg! Here's a whole write up on everything I learned. Unfortunately, you just have to rearrange the files yourself, but thankfully it's exported with everything you need. https://www.nokoriware.com/blog/2021/9/12/java-using-jpackage-quick-start-guide-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest solution is just to check both locations:

```
class ResourceLoader {
    private Path resourceDirectory = null;

    File findResourceFile(String resourceName) {
      if (resourceDirectory == null) {
          if (Path.of("app-folder/res").toFile().isDirectory()) {
              resourceDirectory = Path.of("app-folder/res");
          } else {
              resourceDirectory = Path.of("res");
      }
      return resourceDirectory.resolve(resourceName).toFile();
   }
}
```